# jQuery trigger click on first child

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I'm trying to invoke a click on first `.loader` child when document is ready, but no success:

html:

```
<a class="loader" data-target="david-boy" title="Danny Boy-Rivera">
    <span class="img"><span class="play"></span><img src="img/gallery-image1.jpg" alt="" /></span>
    <h2>Danny Boy</h2>
</a>
```

jQuery:

```
//Does not work
$('a.loader:first-child').bind('click');
$('a.loader:first-child').trigger('click');
$('a.loader:first-child').click();
//Works
$('a.loader:first-child').css("background", "red");
```

Any ideas why?

### Update

Handler:

```
$('.loader').click(function(){
    var name=$(this).data("target");
    callVideo(name);
});
```

### Update2

So the problem was that I had declared the `:first-child` action before the handler. I changed their places and everything ok

Comment: I do have a handler, check update

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you define the handler **before** you initiated the triggered 'click'?

Here's the EXACT same code from your fiddle except I put the handler **BEFORE** the trigger

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.loader').click(function(){
       alert($(this).data("target")); 
    });
    $('.loader:first-child').click();
    $('.loader:first-child').css("background", "red");
});​
```

This will pop the alert you're looking for

Comment: Where did you see his fiddle? I couldn't... :)

Comment: I guess he was referring to the one sent by Bondye

Comment: Maybe, there was a fiddle...sometimes gets jumbled, in any case defining the handler after resulted in nothing happenening, moving it before made it work

Comment: Yet again I shouldn't have assumed that it would have been logical to declare something before calling it, right? :)

Comment: I personally like to be told what it is I have to do before being told to do it...I think anyone with a bad boss can sympathize with this function though.

Comment: Interesting comment :) +1 for the answer to you Likwid_T and @gdoron.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have a handler to the click event...

```
$('a.loader:first-child').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});

$('a.loader:first-child').click();
```

---

**Update:**

You're handler was probably attached before the element was ready.

```
$(function(){
    $('.loader').click(function(){
        var name=$(this).data("target");
            callVideo(name);
    });
});
```